# SQL queries on result table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables ( **Instructors**, **Instructors_config** and **Teach**)  :

**Instructors**

```
instructor_id | first_name | last_name | email | password | status
```

**Instructors_config**

```
instructor_id | profile_pic | fb | twitter | info
```

**Teach**

```
instructor_id | course_id
```

Where **Teach** contain what courses each instructor teach , each instructor can teach multiple courses and each course can be taught by many instructors (many to many relationship )  .

i want to write a function which receive course_id and return all instructors who teach this course along with their fist_name and last_name from **Instructors** Table along with their info from **Instructor_config** table , currently i am using the following query to do that and it works fine  :

```
SELECT instructors.in_id, instructors_config.info, instructors.first_name, instructors.last_name 
FROM instructors 
INNER JOIN instructors_config ON instructors.in_id = instructors_config.in_id 
INNER JOIN teach ON teach.in_id=instructors_config.in_id AND teach.cs_id='.$id
```

but is their  a better or faster way to achieve that or this one is good enough ?

Comment: No idea we need  "show create table Instructors" and "show create table Instructors_config" and "show create table Teach" and "EXPLAIN 
SELECT instructors.in_id, instructors_config.info, instructors.first_name, instructors.last_name 
FROM instructors 
INNER JOIN instructors_config ON instructors.in_id = instructors_config.in_id 
INNER JOIN teach ON teach.in_id=instructors_config.in_id AND teach.cs_id=$id" output... Joins are slow without indexes because off the nested join loop algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Query looks fine but please make sure all below column are indexed properly

```
instructors.in_id,
instructors_config.in_id ,
teach.in_id and 
teach.cs_id
```